# Reformatting the date in a file on file load

Tags: c#, string, date

I'm new to C# and have been battling this challenge for a while and I have come up on a brick wall.

The problem is fairly simple. I have the following file that I am loading into MS SQL:

```
| |500  |RUBBISH_DEFAULT_COLOR_A         |BOB           |24.09.2010|31.12.9999|       |24.09.2010|10:19:42  |               0 |        |        |
| |500  |RUBBISH_DEFAULT_COLOR_A         |MARIE         |02.06.2008|31.12.9999|       |02.06.2008|01:53:04  |               0 |        |        |
| |500  |RUBBISH_DEFAULT_COLOR_B         |JOHN          |30.12.2009|31.12.9999|       |30.12.2009|17:54:27  |               0 |        |        |
| |500  |RUBBISH_DEFAULT_COLOR_C         |RICK          |02.06.2008|31.12.9999|       |02.06.2008|01:53:04  |               0 |        |        |
```

What I'd like to do is create a string reader to fetch the date columns and reorganise them from 02.06.2008 to 2008.06.02 for example. Any thoughts on the simplest quickest way?

The original file being altered is several thousands of lines...

Regards and thanks for any help,

John

Comment: Can you post your sample code that you have up to now? SO is more for specific questions with code than general guidance on things like a string parser... which google might be more useful for. Do you have a string parser setup already?

Answer (score 0):

First you should open the file in any way you like, I used `using` block for a `System.IO.StreamReader` object. My file is located on Desktop so I used `Environment` class to create the path, you can replace your simple path to the file of course.
Then with a `while` block read the file from beginning to end. and for every line I split the string to an array of strings and by converting the date columns to `DateTime` and re-converting to string you will both convert the format and also implicitly check the dates (it will throw a `System.FormatString`)

```
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\sample.txt"))
        {
            while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] columns = line.Split('|');

                try
                {
                    //0 1 2     3                                4              5          6          7       8          9          10                11       12       13
                    // | |500  |RUBBISH_DEFAULT_COLOR_A         |BOB           |24.09.2010|31.12.9999|       |24.09.2010|10:19:42  |               0 |        |        |
                    columns[5] = System.Convert.ToDateTime(columns[5]).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
                    columns[6] = System.Convert.ToDateTime(columns[6]).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
                    columns[8] = System.Convert.ToDateTime(columns[8]).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
                    columns[9] = System.Convert.ToDateTime(columns[9]).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
                    //any changes can be done to string array before submitting to DB
                }
                catch (FormatException ex)
                {
                    // Do something in case of incoorect format.
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("columns[5]:{0}, columns[6]:{1}", columns[5], columns[6]));
            }

        }
```